# Getting results from a third party DLL in C++

Tags: c++, dll

I am very new to software programming.I have been working on a C++ project (using Code::Blocks) and trying to get results from a third party DLL written with Visual C++ 2010. So far I am able to load the DLL using LoadLibrary() and get the function address using GetProcAddress(). But I am not sure how I can proceed further to get some meaningful results. Information from the third party DLL manual is not very clear, at least to me. I would be much appreciated, if someone can point me to the right direction, please.

***DLL information:***

Calcdll.dll exports function StartJob.

StartJob, that accepts three parameters

```
double aInputData[NINPUTDATA], specifies input data
VARIANT aResData[NRESDATA], contains calculation results
VARIANT aOptions[NOPTIONSDATA], specifies optional flags (for future use)

NINPUTDATA: 100
NRESDATA: 100
NOPTIONSDATA 1
```

Usage from C++

```
// Calcdlld.h is located in the installation directory together 
// with calcwin.dll and calcwin.lib
#include “calcdlld.h”
void CCalcdllsvrView::OnCalcolo()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
VARIANT aRis[NRESDATA];
double aInp[NINPUTDATA];
double aOpt[NOPTIONSDATA];
// Collect data from input mask
GetData(vInp);
// Check for errors
if (!StartJob(aInp, aRis, aOpt))
return;
// Show results
ShowResults(aRis);
}

/*
Link Calcdll.lib together with your files.
Warning: positions 14,15 and 30 of the output array contain BSTR values, so in order to convert them to CString (in 
Visual C++) is possible to create an instance of the class CString passing aRis[n].bstrVal to the constructor (see 
VARIANT structure declaration):
*/

CString coilDescription (aRis[29].bstrVal);
AfxMessageBox(CString(“Coil type: “) + coilDescription);

//Contents of calcdlld.h
#define NINPUTDATA 100
#define NOPTIONSDATA 1
#define NRESDATA 100
extern "C" BOOL FAR PASCAL EXPORT StartJob(double vInp[NINPUTDATA], VARIANT vRis[NRESDATA], double vOpt[NOPTIONSDATA]);
```

***My code***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

    double vInp[100];
    VARIANT vRis[100];
    double vOpt[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        vInp[i] = 0;
    }

    //vInp[] = ;
    vInp[0] = 2;
    vInp[1] = 25;
    vInp[8] = 1;
    vInp[9] = 45;
    vInp[14] = 2;
    vInp[15] = 48;
    vInp[16] = 2;
    vInp[17] = 16;
    vInp[18] = 11250;
    vInp[26] = 45;
    vInp[28] = 2.41627;
    vInp[40] = 1;
    vInp[45] = 1;
    vInp[50] = 14;
    vInp[51] = 2.2;
    vInp[60] = 1;
    vInp[61] = 0.11;
    vInp[62] = 0.35;
    vInp[63] = 203;
    vInp[77] = 2;

    cout << "vInp" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        cout << i << ": " << vInp[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Start!" << endl;

    typedef int (__stdcall *f_StartJob)(double vInp[100], VARIANT vRis[100], double vOpt[1]);

    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\......\\calcdll.dll");

    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
        cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        cout << "DLL loaded!" << endl << endl;
    }

    // resolve function address here
    f_StartJob StartJob = (f_StartJob)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "StartJob");
    if (!StartJob) {
        cout << "could not locate the function" << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cout << "StartJob() returned " << StartJob(vInp, vRis, vOpt) << endl;

    cout << vRis << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to get deep to windows programming. It is not easy. I suggest you start with a Win32 tutorial.

Comment: Note: C++ does *not* have a stable ABI. As a general rule, *all your code*, your executable and all libraries you use, need to be compiled with the *exact same* compiler/compiler version for them to be able to interoperate (exceptions exist, but that's the general rule). So you may want to recompile some of your dependencies with your current compiler.

Comment: Please add the expected output and actual output to the question. If there is a lot of output, a description of where the actual output deviates from the expected output may be sufficient.